# Transforming data frame in Spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame here where I need to some transformation. The Col_X and Col_Y here are the columns which need to be worked on. The suffix for Col_X and Col_Y are X and Y and I need this values as in the new column Col_D and the values of Col_x and col_y should be splitted into different rows. I gone through pivot table option but seems to be not working. Is there a way I can transform the data efficiently in Spark scala

```
ColA  ColB Col_x Col_y
a      1     10   20
b      2     30   40
```

Table required:

```
ColA  ColB ColC   Col_D 
a      1     10     X
a      1     20     Y
b      2     30     X
b      2     40     Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` function,

```
val df = // input
df.selectExpr("ColA", "ColB", "stack(2, 'X', Col_x, 'Y', Col_y) as (ColD, ColC)")
    .show()

+----+----+----+----+
|ColA|ColB|ColD|ColC|
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   1|   X|  10|
|   a|   1|   Y|  20|
|   b|   2|   X|  30|
|   b|   2|   Y|  40|
+----+----+----+----+
```